# Get number of skipped blank lines when using CsvHelper?

Tags: c#, .net, csv, .net-core, csvhelper

When you've configured a `CsvReader` with a configuration to skip empty lines by using `IgnoreBlankLines` property of `CsvConfiguration`, how can I go about at getting the count of the skipped lines?

Alternatively, if I don't skip them - how do I track them?

It seems that a blank line is represented by the first field having an empty string as value, and then every other field having null - but this is an implementation detail - i.e, it could be possible that actual data came in this format, or am I wrong?

Comment: In a csv file a blank line would be one column with an empty string, so it should always represent blank lines by the first column being empty and the rest being `null`, though I think you'd only need to check if the second column is `null`.

Comment: @juharr I'll just read the `RawRecord` from the `Parser` object, and check for r/n/ or /n - if there's a miss-match, it means it's not a blank line. Thank you for pointing that out though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your file has a header, you could read the header and then get the row number you are on.  The following example skips two lines so the row is 3 when the header is read.

```cs
void Main()
{
    var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    {
        IgnoreBlankLines = true
    };
    
    using (var reader = new StringReader("\n\nId,Name\n1,One"))
    using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, config))
    {
        csv.Read();
        csv.ReadHeader();
        
        var firstRow = csv.Context.Parser.Row;
        
        var records = csv.GetRecords<Foo>();
        
        Console.WriteLine(firstRow); // 3
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Getting the row number without a header would be only slightly more complicated.

```cs
void Main()
{
    var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    {
        IgnoreBlankLines = true,
        HasHeaderRecord = false
    };
    
    using (var reader = new StringReader("\n\n1,One"))
    using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, config))
    {
        var isFirstRow = true;
        var firstRow = 0;
        var records = new List<Foo>();
        
        while (csv.Read())
        {
            if (isFirstRow)
            {
                firstRow = csv.Context.Parser.Row;
                isFirstRow = false;
            }
            records.Add(csv.GetRecord<Foo>());
        }
        Console.WriteLine(firstRow); // 3
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What's the difference between `Parser.RawRow` and `Parser.Row`? I'm using RawRow.

Comment: Try the 2nd example with `new StringReader("\n\n1,\"One \n Two\"")`.  `RawRow` will give you 4 because the line break between One and Two will technically put you on the 4th row of the document. `Row` will give you 3, since you are logically still on the 3rd row of data.

Comment: Interesting, thank you. I was correct to stick to `RawRow`, as what I'm interested in is the actual line in the file.  I'll mark this as the accepted answer - I used the same technique you demonstrated here, but just didn't have the time to answer it myself, cheers and thank you for answering all these questions regarding CsvHelper! :)

Comment: Yes, it all depends on what you are looking for.  If you are looking for the number of lines skipped and use my second example with `RawRow` it will make it look like you skipped 3 lines instead of the 2 lines you actually skipped to get to your first row of data, since your first row of data takes up 2 actual lines in the file and `RawRow` gives you the actual row you end up on after reading your first line of data.